# Email won't load on iPhone 4s

Tags: iphone, mail.app, ios

Lately my iPhone 4s has been glitching a lot. The latest thing to not work is email. I try to load it and it says "Cannot Get Mail. The mail server 'imap.gmail.com' is not responding. Verify that you have entered the correct account info in mail settings". The thing is - is that I have entered the correct email address. What do I do?

Also - it lets me send emails, just not receive them

Comment: Look at this ; https://discussions.apple.com/message/8459560#8459560

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens to me when the wifi connection is established without Internet connection. Also when the Internet involve passing credentials through a proxy server.

You claim that you're able to send messages but not receive them. Did you verify if those messages are sent? They are usually stored in the outbox waiting to be delivered.